# Changing variable name in for loop

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to run a simple python script that changes a feature to a polygon.

However, I want the outputted polygon to have the same name an the inputted feature. The code that I ran, outputs the name as "lyr", when I really want the name to be the input name. I used "lyr" as a variable name in for the for loop

This is what I have:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\Grounds Project"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\Grounds Project\ZonesMAP.mxd")
Layerlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)


for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    output = r'C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\Grounds Project\DFMGROUNDS.gdb'
    arcpy.FeatureToPolygon_management(lyr, output + '\lyr', '#', 'ATTRIBUTES', '#')
    del lyr

del mxd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fix the line `arcpy.FeatureToPolygon_management(lyr, output + '\lyr', '#', 'ATTRIBUTES', '#')`. Currently you have 'lyr' as a string. Here's an update that uses `lyr` as a variable for your output:

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\Grounds Project"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\Grounds Project\ZonesMAP.mxd")
Layerlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    output = r'C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\Grounds Project\DFMGROUNDS.gdb'
    outfile = os.path.join (output, lyr)
    arcpy.FeatureToPolygon_management(lyr, outfile, '#', 'ATTRIBUTES', '#')

del mxd
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `lyr` variable, instead of defining the string, should work:

```
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    output = r'C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\Grounds Project\DFMGROUNDS.gdb'
    arcpy.FeatureToPolygon_management(lyr, output + '\' + lyr, '#', 'ATTRIBUTES', '#')
    del lyr
```